# How to only print the "Caused by" line of a Java exception?

Tags: java, jvm

When working on Java programs, error stacks can be large and often the only information I need is the "Caused by..." clause. Can I configure the JVM (?) such that it only returns this line?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the JVM, more likely dependent on which logging library you're using.

Comment: Instead of using `e.printStackTrace()` you can use something like `System.err.println(e.getCause())`. I don't think there is any JVM configuration to do that instead of printing the entire stack.

Comment: You'll come to regret this decision. If your program is routinely throwing exceptions, fix that. If it's not, then when one happens, you should appreciate as much context as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the root cause you need to go recursively with `e.getCause()` until it's null and then log the exception where cause is null. But as mentioned in the comments by Michael, it's often a bad idea because you'll be missing out on context sooner or later.

Theres a utility function in Apache Commons to get the root cause: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getRootCause(java.lang.Throwable)

But it would be easy to code it up yourself also if you mind the extra dependency.

Also a thread on how to limit stacktraces with Log4J for example: [how to print only top few stacks in a stacktrace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507316/how-to-print-only-top-few-stacks-in-a-stacktrace-in-java)